# Display a bunch of links as cloud

Tags: php, cloud, hyperlink, tag-cloud, external-links

My client wants me to create a page with a bunch of external links displayed as a cloud. He wants to have the ability to add external links and edit font size and it's color.

This cloud must be located in the center of the page and grow from the center.
I found ready solution, but it doesn't work perfectly and needs to be fixed. I tried to fix it but unfortunately did not succeed.
For example I cannot understand why changing colors doesn't work. Here it is:

```
    <?

      $array = array (
    0 => array ('link' => 'http://123.com', 'name' => 'qq', 'cnt' => 100)
  , 1 => array ('link' => 'http://123.com', 'name' => 'ww', 'cnt' => 2)
  , 2 => array ('link' => 'http://123.com', 'name' => 'ee', 'cnt' => 3)
  , 3 => array ('link' => 'http://123.com', 'name' => 'rr', 'cnt' => 61)
  , 4 => array ('link' => 'http://123.com', 'name' => 'tt', 'cnt' => 5)
  , 5 => array ('link' => 'http://123.com', 'name' => 'yy', 'cnt' => 60)
  , 6 => array ('link' => 'http://123.com', 'name' => 'uu', 'cnt' => 7)
  , 7 => array ('link' => 'http://123.com', 'name' => 'ii', 'cnt' => 8)
  , 8 => array ('link' => 'http://123.com', 'name' => 'iii', 'cnt' => 9)
  , 9 => array ('link' => 'http://123.com', 'name' => 'oo', 'cnt' => 10)
  , 10 => array ('link' => 'http://123.com', 'name' => 'pp', 'cnt' => 11)
  , 11 => array ('link' => 'http://123.com', 'name' => 'aa', 'cnt' => 12)
  , 12 => array ('link' => 'http://123.com', 'name' => 'ss', 'cnt' => 10)
  , 13 => array ('link' => 'http://123.com', 'name' => 'dd', 'cnt' => 11)
  , 14 => array ('link' => 'http://123.com', 'name' => 'ff', 'cnt' => 12)
  , 15 => array ('link' => 'http://123.com', 'name' => 'gg', 'cnt' => 10)
  );

  echo '<div style="font-family:arial; font-size: 10px; width: 300px; text-align: center; position: absolute;
    top: 100px;    left: 50%;    margin-left: -150px;">';
  $params['min_size'] = 100;                    
  $params['max_size'] = 1000;                    
  $params['colors'] = array(0 => 'red', 1 => 'blue', 2 => 'brown', 3 => 'pink', 4 => 'green');
  ntts_cloud_ShowCloud($array, $params);
  echo '</div>';


 function ntts_cloud_FlipArray($array)
    {
      $rows = array_keys($array);
      $first_row_key = $rows[0];
      $cols = array_keys($array[$first_row_key]);

      $rows_cnt = count($rows);
      $cols_cnt = count($cols);

      for($i = 0; $i < $rows_cnt; $i++)
      {
        for($j = 0; $j < $cols_cnt; $j++)
        {
          $result[$cols[$j]][$rows[$i]] = $array[$rows[$i]][$cols[$j]];
        }
      }
      return $result;    
    }


function ntts_cloud_ShowCloud($entries, $config = 0)
    {
      //$entries is array of cloud elements
      //each element should be present as associative array with follows keys 
      //'name' - name of the element
      //'link' - URL
      //'cnt'  - weight of the element


      $colors = array(
      0 => '73cf3b', 
      1 => '000', 
      2 => '000', 
      3 => '000',
      4 => '000', 
      5 => 'red', 
      6 => '000', 
      7 => '000',
      8 => '000', 
      9 => '000', 
      10 => '000', 
      11 => '000',
      12 => '000', 
      13 => '000', 
      14 => '000', 
      15 => '000');                  
      //font size in percent
      $min_size = (isset($config['min_size'])) ? $config['min_size'] : 100;
      $max_size = (isset($config['max_size'])) ? $config['max_size'] : 200;

      if(is_array($config))
      {
        if(isset($config['colors']) && is_array($config['colors']))
        {
          $colors = $config['colors'];
        }
      }


      $flipped = ntts_cloud_FlipArray($entries);
      $min        = min($flipped['cnt']);
      $max        = max($flipped['cnt']);
      array_multisort($flipped['cnt'], SORT_DESC, $flipped['name'], $flipped['link']);
      $entries = ntts_cloud_FlipArray($flipped);

      $shown_entries = array();
      $keys          = array();
      $cnt = count($entries);

      $limit = (isset($config['limit'])) ? min($config['limit'], $cnt) : $cnt;

      for($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++)
      {
        $entries[$i]['cnt'] -= $min;
        if($max > $min)
        {
          $entries[$i]['cnt'] /= ($max - $min);
        }      
        $entries[$i]['cnt'] *= ($max_size - $min_size);
        $entries[$i]['cnt'] += $min_size;
        $entries[$i]['cnt']  = round($entries[$i]['cnt']);
        $key = md5($entries[$i]['name']);
        $shown_entries[$key] = $entries[$i];
        $keys[$i] = $key;
        //проверка корректности url на наличие префикса http://
        if(!preg_match('/^http:/i', $entries[$i]['link'])) 
        {
          $shown_entries[$key]['link'] = 'http://'.$entries[$i]['link'];
        }
      }


      sort($keys);
      $cnt = count($keys);
      $colors_cnt = count($colors);
      for($i = 0; $i < $cnt; $i++)
      {
        $key = $keys[$i];
        $idx = hexdec($key[31]) % $colors_cnt;
        $color = $colors[$idx];
        echo '<nobr><a href='.$shown_entries[$key]['link']
          .' style="font-size:'.$shown_entries[$key]['cnt'].'%; '
          .' text-decoration:none; color: #'.$color.';'
          .'">'.$shown_entries[$key]['name'].'</a></nobr> ' ;
      }

    }



 ?>
```

---

```
<?                 error_reporting(7);


 function ntts_cloud_ShowCloud($entries, $config = 0)
    {

      foreach ($entries as $line)
      {
        echo '<nobr><a href='.$line['link']
          .' style="font-size:'.$line['cnt'].'px; '
          .' text-decoration:none; color: '.$line['color'].';'
          .'">'.$line['name'].'</a></nobr> ' ;
      }

    }

$array = array (
    0 => array ('link' => 'http://1.ru', 'name' => 'kdsf', 'cnt' => 18,'color'=>'red')
  , 1 => array ('link' => 'http://1.ru', 'name' => 'ddd', 'cnt' => 12,'color'=>'green')
  , 2 => array ('link' => 'http://1.ru', 'name' => ' ddd', 'cnt' => 26,'color'=>'black')
  , 3 => array ('link' => 'http://1.ru', 'name' => 'jjj', 'cnt' => 16,'color'=>'blue')
  , 4 => array ('link' => 'http://1.net', 'name' => 'ccc', 'cnt' => 38,'color'=>'#555555')
  , 5 => array ('link' => 'http://1.ru', 'name' => 'llll', 'cnt' => 40,'color'=>'gray')
  , 6 => array ('link' => 'http://1.net', 'name' => 'xxxx', 'cnt' => 15,'color'=>'red')
  , 7 => array ('link' => 'http://1.ru', 'name' => 'wewe', 'cnt' => 23,'color'=>'yellow')
  , 8 => array ('link' => 'http://1.ru', 'name' => 'ddd', 'cnt' => 30,'color'=>'#1234d5')
  );

  echo '<div style="margin-left:30%;font-family:arial; font-size: 10px; width: 300px; text-align: center">';
  ntts_cloud_ShowCloud($array, $params);
  echo '</div>';

  ?>
```

Comment: Which colour do you mean? You should change it in config array or unset `$params['colors']` and change default colours in `ntts_cloud_ShowCloud()` function itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove “#” in this line:

```
.' text-decoration:none; color: #'.$color.';'
```